# "Passing" the hover onto other divs

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I'm building a menu where the nav bar is a fixed size, and the submenus fit the whole screen. I'm doing this in Foundation. In order to achieve this I had to put the submenu's in a different div which has 100% width.

Here is my code:

```
// Script for the NAV BAR submenu

// Puts all submenu items on invisible
$('#submenu div.flyout').hide();

// Starts the hover function
$('ul.nav-bar li').hover(
  function () {
    // Checks which li is hovered
    var index = $("ul.nav-bar li").index(this);
    console.log(index);
    $('#submenu').show();

    // Shows the corresponding sub item
    $('#submenu div.flyout').eq(index).show();
    $('#submenu div.empty').hide();
  },
  function () {
    $('#submenu div.flyout').hide();
        $('#submenu').hide();
  }
);
```

I have a list-item in a navigation bar. When I hover it, it shows a div OUTSIDE the list-item and the navigation bar. When I leave the list-item, the div dissappears, which is supposed to happen. But.. since the div item is supposed to be a submenu, I want it to stay shown when I hover my mouse over that div, thus leaving the list-item.

Does anyone know a solution for this or is it a No Go?

The HTML code

```
<!-- Entire Navbar Code -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <ul class="nav-bar">
                <li class="has-flyout"><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="has-flyout"><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="has-flyout"><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="submenu">

            <div class="flyout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="six columns">
                    <p>Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="six columns">
                    <p>Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. Dit is neptekst. </p>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="flyout empty">
            </div>

            <div class="flyout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="six columns">
                    <p>Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="six columns">
                    <p>Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst. Dit is echte tekst.  </p>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Could you also post the HTML for this please.

Comment: I'm sorry, it could just be me, but could you rephrase your question? I'm having trouble understanding what your problem is. Explain what is happening and what you want/need to happen, please.

Comment: @Joum I have a <li> in a navigation bar. When I hover it, it shows a <div> OUTSIDE the <li> and the navigation bar. When I leave the <li>, the <div> dissapears, which is supposed to happen.

But.. since the div item is supposed to be a submenu, I want it to stay shown when I hover my mouse over that <div>, thus leaving the <li>.

I hope this makes it easier to understand?

Comment: @ninty9notout Also added the HTML

Comment: There is a pure HTML/CSS solution to this. Have a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ninty9notout/p9EJM/

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your code to only call hide when a new menu item is hovered:

*Note: depending on the behavior you want, you will also probably want to call `closeOpenSub()` what the use selects a submenu item.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CJk32/)

```
function closeOpenSub() {
    $('#submenu div.flyout').hide();
    $('#submenu').hide();
}


// Starts the hover function
$('ul.nav-bar li').hover(
  function () {
    // Checks which li is hovered
    var index = $("ul.nav-bar li").index(this);
    console.log(index);

    // hide any open submenus
    closeOpenSub();

    $('#submenu').show();
    // Shows the corresponding sub item
    $('#submenu div.flyout').eq(index).show();
    $('#submenu div.empty').hide();
  }
);
```